# How would l write SQL to label quantities until they run out?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to label quantities (in the `quantity table`) using the labels assigned (see `label assignment` table) until the quantity goes to 0. Then I know that I am done labeling that particular ID.

`label assignment` table is as follows:

```
ID  |  Label | Quantity
 1      aaa      10
 1      bbb      20
 2      ccc      20
```

And my `quantity table`:

```
ID  |  Total Quantity
 1       60
 2       20
```

And I would like to get the following result:

```
ID  |   Label    | Quantity 
 1       aaa         10       (read from reference table, remaining 50)
 1       bbb         20       (read from reference table, remaining 30)
 1       [NULL]      30       (no label in reference table, remaining 0)
 2       ccc         20       (read from reference table, remaining 0)
```

Comment: This is the same as keeping a running total, except that you need to do subtraction instead of addition.  Google "how to do a running total in SQL Server" for examples.

Comment: @TabAlleman: I can see how the running sum would work but am not able to apply to this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer I think, after getting ideas from the other answers: Just create a "FAKE" label for the missing amount:

```
DECLARE @PerLabelQuantity TABLE(Id int, Label varchar(10), Quantity int);
INSERT INTO @PerLabelQuantity 
VALUES (1, 'aaa', 10), (1, 'bbb', 20), (2, 'ccc', 20);

SELECT *
FROM @PerLabelQuantity

DECLARE @QuantityRequired TABLE(Id int, TotalQuantity int);
INSERT INTO @QuantityRequired
VALUES (1, 60), (2, 20);

SELECT *
FROM @QuantityRequired

-- MAKE A FAKE LABEL LET'S CALL IT [NULL] WITH THE AMOUNT THAT IS NOT LABELED
-- i.e. WITH THE REMAINING AMOUNT
-- Probably should be done by copying the original data and the following
-- into a temp table but this is just for proof of concept
INSERT INTO @PerLabelQuantity( Id, Label, Quantity )
SELECT q.ID, 
       NULL, 
       ISNULL(q.TotalQuantity - p.TotalQuantityLabeled, q.TotalQuantity)
FROM @QuantityRequired q
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.ID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantityLabeled 
                 FROM @PerLabelQuantity p 
                 GROUP BY p.Id) p ON 
          p.ID = q.ID
          AND q.TotalQuantity - p.TotalQuantityLabeled > 0

SELECT *
FROM @PerLabelQuantity p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple `JOIN` and `UNION` operation so as to include 'not covered' quantities:

```
SELECT la.ID, la.Label, la.Quantity
FROM label_assignment AS la
INNER JOIN quantity AS q ON la.ID = q.ID

UNION 

SELECT q.ID, NULL AS Label, q.TotalQuantity - la.TotalQuantity  
FROM quantity AS q
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
   FROM label_assignment
   GROUP BY ID
) AS la ON q.ID = la.ID AND q.TotalQuantity > la.TotalQuantity
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e24f/1)

Comment: I figured the union part also but then was trying to use an OVER/PARTITION clause to do a running total and this is where I got stuck... I will try your solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Denis I can't think of a way a running total would be of any use in this case.

Comment: I was thinking that in theory you could keep a running total and then subtract out the running total from the total quantity to see if you need to make the [NULL] label entry. I think your idea is easier...

Comment: If the TotalQuantity needed is less than the number of labels then this will always return the first branch of the union but that will have too high a quantity and/or too many results.  E.g. if the TotalQuantity for ID=1 was 20 we'd expect only 10 bbb labels used.  If it was 10, we'd expect bbb to either not be in the output or be zero.

Comment: @DerekElkins I assume that `Quantity` value present in `label_assignment` table is always less than the corresponding value of `[Total Quantity]` in `quantity ` table.

Comment: @DerekElkins: good point. It would be great to accommodate that situation but I can enforce that with a constraint on the label_assignment table.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @PerLabelQuantity TABLE(Id int, Label varchar(10), Quantity int);
INSERT INTO @PerLabelQuantity 
VALUES (1, 'aaa', 10), (1, 'bbb', 20), (2, 'ccc', 20);

DECLARE @QuantityRequired TABLE(Id int, TotalQuantity int);
INSERT INTO @QuantityRequired
VALUES (1, 60), (2, 20);

SELECT t.Id,
       CASE WHEN o.Overflowed = 1 THEN NULL ELSE t.Label END AS Label, 
       CASE WHEN o.Overflowed = 1 THEN t.QuantityStillNeeded 
            WHEN t.QuantityStillNeeded < 0 THEN t.Quantity + t.QuantityStillNeeded 
            ELSE t.Quantity END AS Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT p.Id, p.Label, p.Quantity,
        MAX(p.Label) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id) AS LastLabel, 
        r.TotalQuantity - SUM(p.Quantity) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id 
                  ORDER BY Label 
                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS QuantityStillNeeded
    FROM @PerLabelQuantity p
    INNER JOIN @QuantityRequired r ON p.Id = r.Id) t
INNER JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) o(Overflowed) 
    ON t.LastLabel = t.Label AND t.QuantityStillNeeded > 0 OR Overflowed = 0
WHERE t.QuantityStillNeeded > -t.Quantity; -- Remove this if you want labels with 
                                           -- 0 quantity used, but you'll need to tweak 
                                           -- the CASE expression for Quantity
```

The subquery calculates a set of used up labels and how many items remain afterward.  If there is any quantity remaining after the last label, then we need to insert a row in the result set.  To do this, I join on a two-element table but the join condition is only true when we are at the last label and there is quantity remaining.  This is probably a confusing way to do this, and we could combine the UNION from George's answer with the subquery from mine to avoid this Overflow table.

Here's the changed (and probably preferable) query:

```
SELECT Id, 
       Label, 
       CASE WHEN QuantityStillNeeded < 0 THEN Quantity + QuantityStillNeeded
            ELSE Quantity END AS Quantity
FROM (SELECT p.Id, p.Label, p.Quantity,
        r.TotalQuantity - SUM(p.Quantity) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id 
                  ORDER BY Label 
                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS QuantityStillNeeded
      FROM @PerLabelQuantity p
      INNER JOIN @QuantityRequired r ON p.Id = r.Id) t
WHERE t.QuantityStillNeeded > -t.Quantity

UNION ALL

SELECT q.Id, NULL AS Label, q.TotalQuantity - la.TotalQuantity AS Quantity
FROM @QuantityRequired AS q
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Id, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
    FROM @PerLabelQuantity
    GROUP BY Id) la ON q.ID = la.ID
WHERE q.TotalQuantity > la.TotalQuantity
```

Comment: There will never be a label with 0 quantity used because there is no point in labeling nothing :-)

Comment: Can you give an explanation of how this is working... The overflow part is a little hard to follow.